# Multilingual - Sitecore General Link Field Url Giving Embedded Language in Wrong Format

Tags: multilingual, sitecore-query, links, link-manager

I have a requirement where my URL should be in format : `http://domain/de-DE/pagename`
I have following settings done for my site:

```
<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage">
    <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
```

For Link Manger Provider i have following properties set:

```
languageEmbedding="always"
addAspxExtension="false" 
alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
encodeNames="true" 
languageEmbedding="always"
languageLocation="filePath" 
lowercaseUrls="true" 
shortenUrls="false" 
useDisplayName="false"
```

Now the issue is, when I am giving internal link in general link for a page say, I am on page http://domain/de-DE/page1 and I have a navigation on which general link field has link of page2.

The expected url is http://domain/de-DE/page2 on navigation link

But I am getting URL as http://domain/de/DE/page2 which is redirecting me to 404 page.

I am fetching the link from general link field using method shown below:

```
 public static string LinkFieldurl(this Item item, ID fieldID)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (ID.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fieldID));
        }
        var field = item.Fields[fieldID];
        if (field == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var linkUrl = new LinkUrl();
        return linkUrl.GetUrl(item, fieldID.ToString());
    }
```

Now this is returning me URL with wrong format of language embedded in URL.

Please suggest me some way in which i can get correct format of language(de-DE) 
or if I am going somewhere wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you should use the `Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField` class and `GetFriendlyUrl()`. To rewrite what you have currently:

```
public static string LinkFieldurl(this Item item, ID fieldID)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    if (ID.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldID))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fieldID));
    }
    LinkField field = item.Fields[fieldID];
    return field?.GetFriendlyUrl() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

By casting your field to a `LinkField`, you should be able to retrieve the resulting URL pretty easily. You'll want to use `GetFriendlyUrl()` as it determines what the target type is (internal, external, media, etc.) and computes the URL accordingly.

You'll always want to set `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` to false. By setting this to true, you're telling Sitecore that you are not using language embedding in the URL and if Sitecore detects a language in the URL to just ignore it and treat it as part of the path. By setting it to true, you are telling Sitecore, yes, there is a language identifier in that path and to strip it out before trying to resolve the path of the item. This is likely your problem with the 404 issue - you've basically told Sitecore that `de-DE` is part of the path to resolve instead of the language embedding.

Comment: Hi chang , thanks for valuable inputs....it helped me.... although I have kept language.AlwaysStripLanguage as true as without it my pages are going to 404, I am still digging and searching for why it's working with true value....it's quiet strange behaving in my sitecore instance....But your inputs gave some idea...